# Optimizing recursive functions with time series data

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization

I have a recursive function, $f(0,a)$ is known, $f(t+1;a,b)=f(t;a,b)+g(t,b)$ where $a,b$ are constants and $g$ is a function. I also have a sequence of data, $D(t)$. I am trying to optimize $f$ with respect to $a,b$ such that:

$argmin_{a,b} \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i (D(i) - f(i;a,b))^2$

Is there a way to optimize for recursive functions such as these? I don't think I can take the derivative wrt. $a,b$ because the function gets more complicated as $t\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

The natural alternative is optimization over the complete state-sequence, i.e. introduce  states $x_i$ as decision variables and then minimize $\sum (D_i-x_i)^2$with constraints $x_{i+1} = f(x_i,a,b) + g(b)$. This is how we often formulate finite-horizon control and estimation problems over dynamical systems in the control community. Many variables, but very sparse and structured.

Another alternative is to see the objective as a black-box, i.e. use a solver where you simply give objective evaluation for current iterate of $(a,b)$. Few variables but information is lost as you do not supply derivative sothe solver has to resort to numerical differentiation (although a least-squares problem in $R^2$ should be trivial unless there is something nasty in the model).

But most importantly, when you say you cannot derive the derivative, do you mean *you* cannot derive the derivative, or do you mean automatic differentiation packages will fail if they are used in a solver equipped with this?

Also, there are methods to compute the gradient specifically for problems of this nonlinear least-squares type estimation problem without explicitly working with the functional expansion of the expression.